# Text overextending past footer DIV tag

Tags: html, css

I've been having problems with my DIV layers - the text goes beyond the DIV footer image, but it's not entirely the DIV background's fault 'cause it DOES repeat... Up to a certain extent. :( I can't seem to figure out how to force the text to stop overextending past the footer DIV tag WHILE keeping the DIV background going.

My "container" element houses the images and the other two elements. The "main" element is where the text goes, and the "footer" element is the image that comes after the end of the text.

[In this image here](http://i43.tinypic.com/244qmoy.jpg), the text goes over the footer image - green arrow is to show where the footer image starts, red arrow is to show where I'd like the text to stop. The background image in the container works for awhile but then stops, so I suppose it doesn't expand correctly...??

I tried to play around with the code to try and fix it - from trying to add padding-top/bottom, to adding the repeating background stretch in the body part, to playing around with the position properties, to trying out the sticky footer (except my layout is only one column... the navigation is part of the layout in the CSS), I just can't seem to get it right.

This is as best as I can get it. :( Do you guys have any helpful solutions and/or tips?? Thanks so much!

Link: http://bubble-wrapped.net

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width:1057px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url(layout/bw-div.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    border:0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 256px;
    left: 126px;
    width: 830px;
    margin: auto;
}

#footer { 
    height: 358px; 
    width: 1057px; 
    bottom: 0;
    position: static;
    background: url(layout/bw-footer.png) no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: You need to either post your code, the HTML, and your CSS, or you need to provide a link to you site.

Comment: @MichaelRader - http://bubble-wrapped.net; I'm still messing with the code here and there, but it shouldn't change too drastically.. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've set the footer to a set height, which is why the text is overflowing.

If you're find with cut-off text, try adding a CSS property to the footer: `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:scroll`.

If you don't want overflow, then try removing the `height` property from the footer or setting it to `height:auto` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I want the text to overflow a little bit, but I also want the DIV background to also continue along with the text - what I'm confused about is that the tag for the text is expanding, but just not correctly.. O.o

Comment: And my link for my layout is here: http://bubble-wrapped.net

Hope this helps clarify my question haha, I'm still pretty new at coding so I'm not entirely sure how to ask correctly - I'm sorry that my question is poorly phrased! :(!

Answer (score 0):

Has to do with position: tag & height: tag

I suspect it has to do with the element within the container and not just the container.

It would help if you would post most of your code so we can see if other things break it.

Your question doesn't really say what your looking to do, which doesn't help us help you.

If its anything like [Possible same situation & answer @StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766693/parent-div-doesnt-expand-with-child-div/8767272#8767272)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't seem like your link's solution helped much. =/ Here's my link, http://bubble-wrapped.net, and I've edited my main post 'cause I just realized my question was kinda cut off, haha.. Sorry about that!